# Toggle - have to click two times

Tags: button, click

I have a code to show a button and with a click on the button checkboxes can be hidden and shown. Now there is the problem that on the first click nothing happens and the second clock on the button hides the "div field".

What can I do that already the first click will work? And how can I hide the "div field" just from the beginning and on a click it appears?

```
<p>Click the button to trigger a function.</p>
            <p class="button" onclick="toggle()">Tennis</p>
            <div id='divSection'>
<div class="jrFieldDiv jrLeft">
  {jr_tennis_label}: {jr_tennis}
</div>


</div>

<script>
               function toggle(){
                   var div = document.getElementById("divSection");
                   if (div.style.display =='block'){
                       div.style.display = 'none';
                       return;
                   }
                   div.style.display ='block';
             }
 </script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's only because on the load of the page your div does not contains block in the display property.
So declare your div as this:

```
<div id="divSection" style="display:block">
```